# Reading gas limit inside solidity smart contract?

Tags: solidity, transactions, gas-limit, gas-price, ethereumjs-tx

As we can read the gas left and the gas price inside solidity smart contract, is there any way that I can read the gas limit set for the transaction inside the solidity ?